# Delete the div with the contents in from mysql contents

Tags: mysql, database, html

I have this code which gets the contents from a mysql databse.

So basically, what happens is that foreach row in the database, it creates a div with the contents in. However, I want the user to be able to delete the post, but I simply can't get my head around how to do it.

This is the code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  $contents= $row['contents'];
}
echo '<div class = "post" style = "margin-right: 300px;">'.$contents.'<br><p>DELETE -- HOW CAN I DO THIS??</p></div>';
```

Basically, what this does is get the contents of the row, each time. But I want the user to be able to click on delete it, and it deletes the div which has the contents, and removes it from the database.

I have tried simply to delete the div, but that deletes ALL the divs, not just the one that I clicked delete in.

How can I do this, I don't care how.

Thanks. I am sorry if there is too much info, or I ask too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out what to do.

Here is what I did:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  $contents= $row['contents'];
  $contentID = $row['contentID'];
}
echo '<div class = "post" style = "margin-right: 300px;">'.$contents.'<br><a href = "delete.php?id='..$contentID'">X</a></div>';
```

And on the `delete.php` I have something like this:

```
$id = 1;
mysql_query("DELETE FROM table_name WHERE $contentID = $id");
```

Comment: You're on the right track, but note your solution is (a) susceptible to [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) attacks and (b) any user can just call delete.php with any ID he or she wishes (thus deleting all content in your DB!).

Answer (score 0):

You need to output a [Delete] link that sends the user back to the server to actually perform the delete.  The deletion from MySQL will occur as a separate request.  The PHP code that handles that request will have to construct a proper DELETE FROM table WHERE id = $id type of SQL statement, and then execute that.  Once that is finished, you'll have to refresh the display so that item is no longer listed - easiest way would be to simply redirect back to the page that you already have.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer my question, as when I click on delete, it deletes all the divs, not just the 1

Comment: Well, you'll have to share the code that does that deletion for me to provide you any more insight as to the specific problem you're dealing with.

Comment: @HBellamy how do you delete the div? none of the code you've added in the example perform any DOM-manipulation.

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson I used jquery to hide it.

Comment: @JakeFeasel Sorry, that jquery code doesn't actually work :/ sorry. Basically, I know how to delete something, but want to know how to delete the div contents

Comment: @HBellamy see my answer on how to delete the div

Answer (score 0):

If you add a class say "delete" to the p-tag

```
<p class="delete">DELETE -- HOW CAN I DO THIS??</p>
```

Then you could delete the div like this, for instance:

```
$(".delete").click(function(){ $(this).parent().remove(); });
```

**Note:**

You would still need some extra functionality, an AJAX-call for instance, to remove the post from the DB and not just from the DOM.